# NTILE function in Mysql get to well distribution over column

Tags: mysql, mysql-function

Hi this query i am trying to run in MySQL to get well distribution over my ID but looks like some issue in syntax .

```
select min(ID), max(ID),count(*), nt from ( select ID, ntile(16) over (order by ID) nt from table) group by nt order by nt;
```

This is working in Oracle but not MySQL may be looks like its not available in MySQL 5.7 .
How else can we get this data ?

Basically i have UUID application generated which can be ordered and in need to organize and group and then divide in 16 segment .

Expected output

```
MIN(ID)                                 MAX(ID)                       COUNT(*)               NT                                                           
                                                         
00000000-ebc5-4d19-9d7b                 0a360b83-6d9a-17d7-9b67            36282227          1                   
0a360b83-6d9a-17d7-9b67                 0a360b85-6ebb-1bbc-9bbb            36282227          2
```

Comment: Window functions were introduced in Mysql in version 8.0

Comment: Yes but is there any way i can get this in some other way

Comment: Could you provide some sample data?

Comment: @D-Shih I have shared some sample data

Comment: Do 16 segments need to order? if the answer was yes it would be very tough to do that.

Comment: @D-Shih Yes so the idea is i have to migrate data from MySQL to another server and to parallelize i need to split logically .If that is not in order then there is chance we loose some data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## NTILE for MYSQL 5,7 And Mariadb 10.1

**and prior versions**

It takes a bit of logic and if you like you can debug it

The first is my application, the second is the mysql 80 version of your query for comparison

I would still recommend upgrading your mysql version

The main  part is

```
 @mod:=countr % 16, @div:=countr DIV 16
```

Where you determine which number of tiles you need

> ```
> SELECT 
>     MIN(ID), MAX(ID), COUNT(*), nt
> FROM
>     (SELECT 
>         `ID`,
>             IF(@countr < @div2, @ntile, @ntile:=@ntile + 1) AS nt,
>             IF(@countr < @div2, @countr:=@countr + 1, @countr:=1) c1,
>             IF(@ntile <= CAST(@mod AS UNSIGNED), @div2:=@div + 1, @div2:=@div) div2
>     FROM
>         (SELECT 
>         ID, @mod:=countr % 16, @div:=countr DIV 16, @div2:=@div
>     FROM
>         table1, (SELECT 
>         COUNT(*) countr
>     FROM
>         table1, (SELECT @ntile:=1, @countr:=0, @div2:=0) t3) t2) t1
>     ORDER BY ID) t1
> GROUP BY nt
> ORDER BY CAST(nt AS UNSIGNED);
> ```

> 

> ```
> select 
> min(ID)
> , max(ID)
> ,count(*)
> , nt 
> from 
> ( select 
>       ID
>         , ntile(16) over (order by ID) nt 
>   from table1)  t1
> group by nt order by nt;
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5fec21d4c0bce3c33bd81d09a4d06e7a)*

Comment: Can you please remove those IDS its working for me thank you so much ..I am not able to migrate to 5.8 Because i am using Aurora and in AWS its not released yet

Comment: i don't see why, nobody ca do anything with it anyway. Is there a good cause why you didin't upvte the answer?

Comment: Thanks nbk It took time for me to understand script  so waited to test but all good thanks again